# Does fs.readFileSync block the thread Node is running?

Tags: node.js

I know that `fs.readFileSync` blocks my code, but does it also block the thread in which the Node server is running?

Is `fs.readFileSync` just syntactic sugar for `fs.readFile`?

Comment: if its block your code then its block the thread (: as your code i just 1 part of the event loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it might vary based on your code, but consider the difference in what happens whenever you run the following:

This will be our server code:

```
const http= require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("Got request");
    res.end("Hello\n");
}).listen(3000);
```

If we run `fs.readFileSync()` and try to load `/dev/urandom` (which won't complete):

```
const f = fs.readFileSync("/dev/urandom");
console.log(f);
```

And try to access the server with cURL, the request will never finish because node is tied up trying to finish the file read.

In contrast, if we use `fs.readFile()`:

```
fs.readFile("/dev/urandom", f => {
    console.log(f);
});
```

Whenever we run cURL, we get a request and we see "Got request" in the server process because node *isn't* tied up with loading the file.

So to answer your question: no, `readFileSync` is not just syntactic sugar for `readFile`.

Comment: Wow! It means a simple mistake can block the whole web server?

Comment: @OldGeezer, no it means that you should avoid using synchronous APIs.  Node's philosophy is to be "asynchronous" and "event driven".  Some say that there is a place where it makes sense to use synchronous APIs like `readFileSync` but I still haven't encountered one.

Comment: @OldGeezer I mean, it's still easy to lock yourself into a long running loop even using I/O, and in any language.  node tries to solve deadlocking and resource starvation by trying to get you to follow the notion of "I'll let you know when it's done" rather than, "I'll wait till you're done" approach.

Comment: why to use sync api where we can do await on async. which will not block main node thread. :)

Comment: @AnonymousCreator There are very few cases where it makes sense, and most of them are up to preference anyway.  If your entire program depends on a config file that must be loaded before anything else can be done, you *could* nest the rest of your program in a callback to `readFile`, or you could just write a `readFileSync` at the onset of your program and forgo the indentation it would cause.  I can't think of a reason you would otherwise.

Comment: @zero298 correct. that can be one use case.